# if (string.contains) mixing up variable placement in final output

Tags: java, string, contains

I'm writing a program to generate html metadata based on product title. All the program asks for (at the moment) is the product title and 2 other details. This is the current incorrect output:

```
Please paste model title.
```

(MY INPUT: Bugatti Veyron 1:18 Blue)

```
<METANAME="DESCRIPTION"CONTENT="Shop for Bugatti diecast model cars at [WEBSITE REMOVED]">
<METANAME="ABSTRACT"CONTENT=Shop for diecast model cars at [WEBSITE REMOVED].
<METANAME="KEYWORDS"CONTENT=“diecast cars, diecast quality scale cars,
diecast model cars, model cars, collectible cars, Veyron diecast model, quality diecast   cars, diecast 1:18">
```

What I would want is:

```
Please paste model title.
```

(MY INPUT: Bugatti Veyron 1:18 Blue)

```
<METANAME="DESCRIPTION"CONTENT="Shop for Bugatti Veyron 1:18 Blue diecast model cars at [WEBSITE REMOVED]">
<METANAME="ABSTRACT"CONTENT=Shop for diecast model cars at [WEBSITE REMOVED].
<METANAME="KEYWORDS"CONTENT=“diecast cars, diecast 1:18 scale cars,
diecast model cars, model cars, collectible cars, diecast model, Bugatti diecast cars, diecast Veyron">
```

Note the differences being the title isn't the title, just one word out of it. The scale is put at the end instead of where it should be, etc.

The code, in a truncated fashion to avoid posting 300+ lines is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MetagenV3 {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String title;
    String abstr = "Shop for diecast model cars at [WEBSITE REMOVED]";
    String scale;
    String diecastManu;
    String metaModel;
    String metaMake;
    String defaultstring = "quality";

    String[] metaMakesList = {"Abarth", "Acura", "Ahrens", "Alfa Romeo"
            +"Alpine Renault", "AMC", "American LaFrance", "Aprilia", "Aston Martin" 
            +"Audi", "Austin", "Austin-Healey", "Bedford", "Benelli", "Bentley", "BMW"
            +"Buffalo", "Bugatti", "Buick","Cadillac","Caterham", "Chaparrel"
            + "Checker","Chevrolet","Chrysler","Citroen", "Cleveland", "Cord","DAF"
            + "Daimler","Dakota","Datsun","Dauer"}; // ETC ETC

    String[] scaleList = {"1:12","1:18","1:24","1:32","1:43","1:64"}; // ETC ETC

    System.out.println("Please paste model title.");
    title = sc.next();

    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[0].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[0];}
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[1].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[1];}
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[2].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[2];}
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[3].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[3];}
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[4].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[4];}
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(metaMakesList[5].toLowerCase()))
    { metaMake = metaMakesList[5];}
    // ETC, ETC

    else {
        metaMake = defaultstring;
    }

    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[0].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[0]; }
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[1].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[1]; }
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[2].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[2]; }
    if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[3].toLowerCase()))
    { scale = scaleList[3]; }
    // ETC, ETC

    else { scale = defaultstring;}

    System.out.println("Please paste model manufacturer.");
    diecastManu = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please paste car model (e.g Skyline");
    metaModel = sc.next();


String fullOutput = "<METANAME="  + "\"DESCRIPTION\"" + "CONTENT=\"" + "Shop for " + title + " "
        + "diecast model cars at [WEBSITE REMOVED]\"" +">" + "\n"
            + "<METANAME="  + "\"ABSTRACT\"" + "CONTENT=" + abstr + "\n"
         +  "<METANAME="  + "\"KEYWORDS\"" + "CONTENT=" + "“diecast cars, diecast " + scale + " "
                + "scale cars," + "\n" + "diecast model cars, modelcars, collectable cars, "
         + diecastManu + " diecast"
                        + " model, " + metaMake + " diecast cars, diecast " + metaModel +"\">";

System.out.println(fullOutput);

}
```

}

Additionally it also ignores:

```
   System.out.println("Please paste model manufacturer.");
        diecastManu = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please paste car model (e.g Skyline");
        metaModel = sc.next();
```

I know this question is long and not very simple, but I can't think of a better way to show what's going on.

Comment: You have a lot of if statements, but no else-if statements.

Comment: Would it be cleaner to change the if into switch? I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You should check out the documentation for `Scanner.next()`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(). Your call to `next()` is only returning the first word. You should also try running this through a debugger, to see the actual values being stored from your input, and which `if` statements are being hit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are multiple layers of your question, but the first issue you mention of the title is straight forward.

This code

```
System.out.println("Please paste model title.");
title = sc.next();
```

will only read in the first word. Scanner.next() will only read the first token based on the delimiter (space by default).

I would recommend you walk through the code with a debugger of some sort (if you have one). Failing that, you should add some print statements to help see what the code is doing.

For example, if you add

```
System.out.println("Please paste model title.");
title = sc.next();
System.out.println("Title: " + title);
```

You will immediately see the issue is that the program is not reading the input correctly.

Additionally, this explains why it is appearing to ignore the manufacturer and car model prompts. It is reading the remaining tokens from the model title.

UPDATE (see comment)
The final else is always triggering

```
if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[2].toLowerCase()))
{ scale = scaleList[2]; }
if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[3].toLowerCase()))
{ scale = scaleList[3]; }
else { scale = defaultstring;}
```

Suppose scaleList[2] is correct. It will set scale to scaleList[2], then it will evaluate the next if statement. It will be false, detect the else block and run that. The correct way to structure these related if statements is

```
if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[2].toLowerCase()))
{ scale = scaleList[2]; }
else if (title.toLowerCase().contains(scaleList[3].toLowerCase()))
{ scale = scaleList[3]; }
else { scale = defaultstring;}
```

This way as soon as it finds the correct scale, it will stop attempting to match scales (this is also relevant for your make).

Comment: That makes more sense now. I used the .nextLine method on the title,  that sorted the issue out. Now the only problem with it is that it is ignoring the scale if statements and skipping to the default every time. Is there something wrong with the if statements? Do they require an else-if clause?

Comment: Related if conditions should be structure into if-else blocks. What is happening is the final else is always triggering. I'll update my answer

Comment: As an edit to my previous comment, still nothing is working with the if statements and the program still fails. I changed it to this structure: if, else if, else if [etc] else.  Is that right for this case?

Comment: I believe so. In the situation where only one thing should be true, they should be chained together with if-else. If multiple can be true, they should be independent without else.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but unfortunately it's still doing it, even after they have been chained together like: if, else if, else if, else.